# Fragment transaction with animation blacks out google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am having some issues with how to determine when a Fragment transaction is actually complete.

The problem is that my Fragment transaction has an animation that lasts for 250ms, if the user manages to press the backPress button before the animation is complete, it will give me a black map.

This is my code for starting the transaction

```
    public void startTransactionAnimated(BaseFragment fragment, int startEnter, int startExit, int endEnter, int endExit) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(startEnter, startExit, endEnter, endExit);
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

fragmentHandler.startTransactionAnimated(toiletPageFragment,
            R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.exit_to_right);
```

The different animations all have a 250ms duration.

Normal view:

[image: Normal View]

Black map:

[image: Black Map]

I have tried to `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` but without any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I actually made it work. It was quite some work but it is done!

Here is what I did.

I have a BaseFragment class that extends Fragment.

```
protected void onAnimationStarted () {}

protected void onAnimationEnded () {}

protected void onAnimationRepeated () {}

    @Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation (int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    //Check if the superclass already created the animation
    Animation anim = super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim);

    //If not, and an animation is defined, load it now
    if (anim == null && nextAnim != 0) {
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), nextAnim);
    }
    //If there is an animation for this fragment, add a listener.
    if (anim != null) {
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart (Animation animation) {
                onAnimationStarted();
                Log.i("TESTTAG", "ANIM STARTED: " );
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) {
                Log.i("TESTTAG", "ANIM END: " );
                onAnimationEnded();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation) {
                onAnimationRepeated();
            }
        });
    }
    return anim;
}
```

Here I added this. This made it possible to override the *onAnimationStart* and *onAnimationEnded* in the fragment I use.

```
    @Override
protected void onAnimationStarted() {
    super.onAnimationStarted();
    isAnimationDone = false;
}

@Override
protected void onAnimationEnded() {
    isAnimationDone = true;
    super.onAnimationEnded();
}
```

Here I set a boolean to see if the animation has actually ended.

Then on my *backPress* in fragment which is a custom method I have created to catch the backPress event, I added this code.

```
    @Override
public void doBack() {
    if (isAnimationDone){
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

The animation will now complete and therefore the user can't get the black map issue.